# Visual Studio Code not stopping on uncaught exceptions in angular app

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

Previously I´ve been debugging my angular app with chrome, but I want to try debugging using visual studio code. Currently, what works is stopping on manualy set breakpoints and stopping on any exception if I have "All exceptions" ticked in the breakpoints setting of the debug view. However since that setting stops on anything it is basicaly unusable. So what I would like to use is the "Uncaught exceptions" setting. It just doesnt work, even simple stuff like trying to access a property on an undefined variable doesnt stop the code.
In case it is of any relevance, I am using "Debugger for Chrome" to be able to use breakpoints inside vs code.